# Configuring open fire server in ubuntu

Tags: xmpp

I have installed open fire 3.8.1 in my system. I have also enabled the monitoring service plugin by jive software. It logs all the conversations in the database. Few days back some one have changed the settings and now the conversations are not recorded in the database. How to re-enable open fire to store chat logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option inside the console where you should be able to just re-enable it if someone turned it off. It's under the monitoring section like you said. Or you can reinstall the plug altogether by going in the plug-ins section and reinstalling it again.